# RouteNotFoundException when trying to delete a custom entity

Tags: 8, entities, routes

I am building a custom component in Drupal 8 that has an entity with child entities i.e., TeamEntity has one or more MeetEntity objects.

When I navigate to the "Delete" link for a given MeetEntity, I get the following error:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "entity.meet_entity.collection" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName() (line 191 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php).
Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->getRoute('entity.meet_entity.collection') (Line: 285)
Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->generateFromRoute('entity.meet_entity.collection', Array, Array, 1) (Line: 110)
Drupal\Core\Render\MetadataBubblingUrlGenerator->generateFromRoute('entity.meet_entity.collection', Array, Array, 1) (Line: 754)
Drupal\Core\Url->toString(1) (Line: 161)
Drupal\Core\Utility\LinkGenerator->generate(Object, Object) (Line: 99)
Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Link::preRenderLink(Array)
call_user_func(Array, Array) (Line: 384)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) (Line: 451)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) (Line: 451)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 200)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 471)
Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object, Array, 'html', NULL, 1) (Line: 43)
__TwigTemplate_4a2ed85f2bf4ceab0412cdb1168c80023104264819c7f1db9b016550543c33e9->doDisplay(Array, Array) (Line: 381)
Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array) (Line: 355)
Twig_Template->display(Array) (Line: 366)
Twig_Template->render(Array) (Line: 64)
twig_render_template('core/themes/classy/templates/form/confirm-form.html.twig', Array) (Line: 389)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('confirm_form', Array) (Line: 438)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 200)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, ) (Line: 231)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}() (Line: 577)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 232)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 122)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 95)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 116)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object) (Line: 144)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 62)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 62)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 53)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 103)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 82)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 55)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 632)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

I have a "collection" link defined in my MeetEntity class like this:

```
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/meet/{meet_entity}",
 *     "add-form" = "/team/{team_entity}/meet/add",
 *     "edit-form" = "/meet/{meet_entity}/edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "/meet/{meet_entity}/delete",
 *     "collection" = "/team/{team_entity}/meets",
 *   },
```

I don't have that route defined in my routing.yml file because that "collection" path defined in the links in my Entity class points to a view called "views.view.meets.yml". However, when I do add a route for that in my routing.yml file, I get a `MissingMandatoryParametersException` on the {team_entity}

I imagine I need to override some method somewhere but I can't figure out where. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. I had to override both `Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityDeleteFormTrait::getRedirectUrl()` and `Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityDeleteFormTrait::getCancelUrl()` in my `MeetEntityDeleteForm` class. Here's my code:

```
public function getRedirectUrl() {
    $entity = $this->getEntity();
    return Url::fromRoute('view.meets.page_1', ['arg_0',$entity->getTeamId()]);
}

public function getCancelUrl() {
    return $this->getRedirectUrl();
}
```

`arg_0` in the call to `fromRoute` is the Team ID defined in the view's contextual relationship to the Team entity.

I was able to keep the `meet_entity.collection` route **out** of my routing.yml file. And my delete_form route was very simple:

```
entity.meet_entity.delete_form:
  path: '/meet/{meet_entity}/delete'
  defaults:
    # Calls the form.delete controller, defined in the team entity.
    _entity_form: meet_entity.delete
    _title: 'Delete Meet'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'meet_entity.delete'
```